# Can JProfiler be run without the GUI?

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler

Is it possible to run JProfiler to profile an application without having to launch the GUI, select the application, etc?

I'd like to be able to run a set of executions of my application and save the profiling results in an automated way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the offline profiling capability from JProfiler:

> JProfiler's offline profiling capability allows you to run profiling sessions from the command line without the need for starting JProfiler's GUI front end. Offline profiling makes sense if you want to
>
> - perform profiling runs from a scripted environment (e.g. an ant build file)
> - save snapshots on a regular basis for QA work
> - profile server components on remote machines via slow network connections

Reference: [JProfiler Docs](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/index.html)

Comment: Also see this screen cast about triggers and offline profiling: http://blog.ej-technolgies.com/2010/03/offline-profiling-and-triggers.html

Comment: Thanks Pedro! I definitely didn't pay much attention to the documentation!